# Move item rename original item

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to have PowerShell check if the file exists in two locations - the source folder and destination folder. If it does exist in both, I'd like it to append `"voided"` to the destination file then move the source file to destination location.

I found the below script which works, but it renames the source file and not the one in the destination folder. I've searched and tired to reverse the script but in all scenarios I was only able to get it to rename the source file. What am I missing?

```
$src = "c:\Temp\Invoice"
$dest = "c:\Temp\test"
$v = "voided"

Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Filter *.pdf -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $nextName = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $_.name

    while (Test-Path -Path $nextName) {
        $nextName = Join-Path $dest ($_.BaseName + "_$v" + $_.Extension)
    }

    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $nextName
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't modify `$nextName`. Rename the destination file before moving the source file.

```
if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $nextName) {
  Rename-Item -LiteralPath $nextName -NewName ($_.BaseName + "_$v" + $_.Extension)
}

$_ | Move-Item -Destination $nextName
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to all this myself, but please try the below and let me know if you have any issues?

```
$sourceFolder = "\\root\source\folder"
$destinationFolder = "\\root\destination\folder"    
$v = "voided"    

#Get just the file names for the items in your source folder
$filesInSource = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter *.PDF -Recurse | select Name


#join-path will stick the two variables together as a full file path
Join-Path -Path $destinationFolder -ChildPath $filesInSource | Where-Object {Test-Path $_} | ForEach-Object {
    #Renames the file in the $destinationFolder
    Rename-Item -NewName ($_.BaseName + "_$v" + $_.Extension)
    #Moves the item from the $sourceFolder into the $destinationFolder keeping original name
    Move-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $sourceFolder -ChildPath $filesInSource) -Destination $destinationFolder
}
```

This looks like it will work to me, but like I said, I'm still learning. I've tried to comment on it to explain what is happening at each point